# ln command breaks when there is a space in filename

Tags: bash, ln

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in instances/*; do
        #echo $i
        if [[ -d "${i}/.minecraft/" ]]; then
                echo "${i}/.minecraft/"
                if [ -h "${i}/.minecraft/saves" ]; then
                        rm -f "${i}/.minecraft/saves"
                else rm -rf   "${i}/.minecraft/saves";
                fi
                ln -s saves '"'${i}/.minecraft/saves'"'
        fi
done
```

this is my script for linking up the saves in my PolyMC setup.
the problem is that the code doesnt work if DIRECTORY has a space:

`instances/1.19 Sodium/.minecraft/` this has the following output:

`ln: target 'Sodium/.minecraft/saves"': No such file or directory`

also removing '"' still has the same error

Comment: `'"'` What are you tring to do with this? Just use `"${i}/.minecraft/saves"`.

Comment: You aren't quoting the parameter expansion; you're trying to add quotes to the *results* of the expansion.

Comment: Why are you quoting the `ln` arguments differently from the `echo` and `rm` arguments?

Comment: @tkausl its a cool hack i found that fixed an ffmpeg automation script

Comment: Its not a _cool hack_, it was put there for a purpose and that purpose doesn't apply to your code, so don't use it.

Comment: it wont work without it either. also what is does is it passes on the double qoute, which i have i found, helps when commands are sensitive to white spaces

Comment: @tkausl can you suggest changes, removing `"'"` still gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

As everyone already commented, it's **not** about removing the `'"'` but to quote your `$i` inside double quotes. Nor is it a random combination of " and ' to make it work.

Explanations :

When `i` contains a space like : `i="1.19 Sodium"` (here the double quotes are delimiters, not characters of the string),

the line `ln -s saves '"'${i}/.minecraft/saves'"'`

is seen as :

`ln -s  saves '"'1.19 Sodium/.minecraft/saves'"'`

In this context, single quotes are string delimiters, while double quotes are any (unwanted) characters in the string.

It is read as :

1. The word `ln`,
2. A *field separator*,
3. The word `-s`,
4. A *field separator*,
5. The word `saves`,
6. A string (delimited by single quotes) of one character `"` concatenated to the word `1.19`,
7. The space (coming from `i`) interpreted (since outside quotes) as a *field separator*,
8. The word `Sodium/.minecraft/saves` concatenated to a string (delimited by single quotes) of one character `"`.

Then it's exactly equivalent to :
`ln   -s   saves   '"1.19'   'Sodium/.minecraft/saves"'`

Which is not what you want, and why the error message says `Sodium/.minecraft/saves"` does not exist.

As @tkausl commented, the solution is `"${i}/.minecraft/saves"` (or without the braces `"$i/.minecraft/saves"`).

With this, when `i` contains a space like : `i="1.19 Sodium"`,

the line `ln -s saves "$i/.minecraft/saves"`

is seen as :

- `ln   -s   saves   '1.19 Sodium/.minecraft/saves'`,
- or (equivalent) `ln   -s   saves   "1.19 Sodium/.minecraft/saves"`,
- or (equivalent) `ln   -s   saves   1.19\ Sodium/.minecraft/saves`.

With the correction, any space in `i` will no longer be interpreted as a field separator because `i` is in a string delimited by double quotes.

Conclusion: Never use non-quoted variables (even `echo "$i"` instead of `echo $i`).

Comment: Just to note, the single quotes are not string *delimiters*. They (and double quotes) are just a form of bulk escaping; every character inside the quotes is treated as if it were preceded by a backslash (with some exceptions inside double quotes).

Comment: @chepner Yes I should have emphasized that it wasn't in a potential technical word sense that I was using it (I used italic for "field separator" only). I didn't know how else to say it in this context. Example of not string delimiters: `cmd0 "$(cmd1 "$var2")"` :-)